# ssrs dataset IIF condition not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I can't figure out the syntax error in this statement,

[image]

```
" & IIF(Parameters!Product_type_name.Value<>"AllType","and product_type_name='" &  Parameters!Product_type_name.Value & "'","") & "
```

The logic is, if "AllType" is passed into the product_type_name, then we will have a product_type_name filter.

Else, it will just return nothing.

There seems to be something wrong with escape sequences.

[image]

Comment: SSRS parameters passed to a query are passed like `@parameterName` just like a declared variable.

Comment: i've inherited this, so this appears to be the old way of passing in parameters. I'm just sticking with this in the mean time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how to pass parameters to a SQL statement in SSRS

eg: `y.facility = @Facility` will do

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337432(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: it turns out i will not be using the whole string above, so this is no longer an issue for me. But the next time I encounter something like this, i will definitely try to fallback to your suggestion here.